# How a matrix in SL(2,R) can be seen as a product of symmetric matrix and a rotation one

Tags: lie-groups

I'm reading Gilmore's Lie Group, Physics and Geometry and I'm trying to solve the exercise 1 at page 8, in which you have to find the full parametrization of a 2X2 $SL(2,R)$ matrix as a product of a symmetric matrix and a rotation one.
While retrieving the rotation matrix is really simple, I'm struggling to find a suitable parametrization for the symmetric part.
The book is claiming this is a 2-Manifold which can be parametrized by the two-sheeted hyperboloid $$z^2 - x^2 -y^2 = 1$$

Initially I thought to simply write the symmetric matrix as: $$\begin{bmatrix}z+x & y\\y & z-x\end{bmatrix}$$

which determinant is 1, but this is not a 2-Manifold, since showing 3 degree of freedom.

I've also tried the hyperbolic parametrization, i.e.:
$$\begin{align} x=sinh(u)cos(v) \\ y=sinh(u)sin(v) \\ z=\pm cosh(u)\end{align}$$

, which is better but I cannot see how to put this explicitly in matrix form, to get the determinant = 1.

I'm sure it's related to the KAN decomposition of a $SL(2,R)$ matrix, somehow.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just realised that combining the 2 claims above we could write keep my symmetric 3-Manifold symmetric matrix replacing the hyperbolic relations and getting a symmetric matrix un u and v, but which solution to keep for the z?
Choosing the + may work:

$$\begin{bmatrix}cosh(u)+sinh(u)cos(v) & sinh(u)sin(v)\\sinh(u)sin(v) & cosh(u)-sinh(u)cos(v)\end{bmatrix}$$

What do you think about this, please?

Comment: Why your first matrix try is not a 2-manifold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix you added in your edit is correct.  The choice of $z=+cosh(u)$ and $z=-cosh(u)$ is exactly what makes the hyperboloid two-sheeted, since $cosh(u)$ is strictly positive.

Comment: Thank @ChainedSymmetry for your confirmation. However, my worry about the $\pm$ sign is still there. I mean, my final matrix is made by choosing $z=+cosh(u)$ in both z entries. But there is a twin matrix admitting $z=-cosh(u)$ as well. So I was puzzling  which one is better or if they are equivalent. EDIT: probably what you meant is my matrix choice represents the upper fold, while the other one would make the bottom one. So probably there's not a unique matrix representing both?

Comment: That's right.  You have to pick a sheet to do anything computationally, though I suppose you could represent both sheets in one matrix by writing $\pm cosh(u)$.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks for your support

Comment: Why the first matrix try he did is not a 2-manifold?